# Опечатка в неотвеченных вопросах

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

На [основном сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) и [на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) если перейти к неотвеченным вопросам, в разделе меток (справа) заголовок с опечаткой - "Метки в неотвеченные вопросах".

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня на Мете, кстати, [списка меток не отображается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhvC.png) при пустом избранном наборе. Это только при выборе вкладки "мои метки", как оказалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266363?key=d895887e05bd4ce99e47204f2362a2e5):

> Метки в неотвеченных вопросах

Будет доступно после подгрузки базы строк.